# How to get join/leave messages or events from teams chats

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I work on making a parser for teams export data / pst format using Aspose lib for eDiscovery tool. Can the events like user joined or left a channel be exported from Teams and found in data ?

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to us We will investigate and if we require further information we will reach out. Best regards, Teams Platform

Comment: Could you please update your query with more information? it seems you are looking for Event details check it out this [Event resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Answer (score 0):

Aspose.Email doesn't seem to serve what you have requested at the moment . However, I have added a ticket with ID **EMAILNET-39875** as investigation to further evaluate it. We will share the feedback with you as soon as we will complete investigation.

FYI: Aspose.Email API supports managing the entities mentioned in following image if stored inside PST.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWgoL.png

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose and I like to assist in queries related to Aspose product families.